# Get display name that matches that found in display settings

Tags: c#, wpf

While writing a WPF application, I want to get the names of the displays found in the standard windows display settings dialog.  I've tried WMI querying Win32_DesktopMonitor, and System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.

The names that show in the standard windows display settings list are:

```
Mobile PC Display
DELL 2407WFP
```

Win32_DesktopMonitor provides the following (stripped of unrelated info):

```
DISPLAY 1
Caption = Generic PnP Monitor
CreationClassName = Win32_DesktopMonitor
Description = Generic PnP Monitor
DeviceID = DesktopMonitor1
MonitorManufacturer = (Standard monitor types)
MonitorType = Generic PnP Monitor
Name = Generic PnP Monitor
PNPDeviceID = DISPLAY\DELA017\5&2F0149CC&0&UID1078064

DISPLAY 2
Caption = Generic PnP Monitor
CreationClassName = Win32_DesktopMonitor
Description = Generic PnP Monitor
DeviceID = DesktopMonitor2
MonitorManufacturer = (Standard monitor types)
MonitorType = Generic PnP Monitor
Name = Generic PnP Monitor
PNPDeviceID = DISPLAY\CMO1720\4&164FD10C&0&UID67568640
```

System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens provides a list of devices (stripped of unrelated info):

```
DISPLAY 1
DeviceName = \\.\DISPLAY1

DISPLAY 2
DeviceName = \\.\DISPLAY3
```

Clearly I should be able to cross reference the DeviceName, DeviceID or PNPDeviceID with a list somewhere else to get the name, no?

Please don't bust me for this, I've googled everything I could think of and all I ever find is info about AllScreens and Win32_DesktopMonitor, but nothing about finding the display names we see in the standard windows display settings dialog.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone asked this exact same question on the [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/3a72ec6b-828d-424b-b912-117f7071bb94).

There are two relevant answers in that which I'll duplicate here:

> I am not sure exactly what you mean by monitor name, the unique
>   monitor name?  If when you call [EnumDisplayDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609.aspx) to enumerate the
>   monitor you can specify the following flag:
>   EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME then in the DeviceID field of the
>   DISPLAY_DEVICE structure you will see the unique monitor name.

followed by:

> Thanks, your solution was almost 100% there.  The only thing I needed
>   to add was a second call to [EnumDisplayDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609.aspx) and passing in the
>   DeviceName returned from the first call.  Then the DeviceName is
>   populated with the Monitor's name and not the Video card.  Perfect!

I haven't done this myself, so I can't verify that it works, but it seems encouraging based on the OP of the MSDN thread saying it worked for him.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completedness, here's the actual code that resembles the MSDN answer:

```
DISPLAY_DEVICE DisplayDevice = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
const int EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME = 0x1;
int NumberOfMonitor = 0 /* You can either iterate over EnumDisplayDevices until
                           it returns false for the number of attached monitors,
                           or use 0 for the primary monitor.*/

EnumDisplayDevices(null, NumberOfMonitor, ref DisplayDevice, 0)) {
EnumDisplayDevices(DisplayDevice.DeviceName, NumberOfMonitor, ref DisplayDevice, EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME);
```

The `DisplayDevice` object is a struct called [DISPLAY_DEVICE](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/DISPLAY_DEVICE.html):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct DISPLAY_DEVICE 
{
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
      public int cb;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=32)]
      public string DeviceName;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=128)]
      public string DeviceString;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
      public DisplayDeviceStateFlags StateFlags;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=128)]
      public string DeviceID;
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=128)]
      public string DeviceKey;
}
```

Comment: DISPLAY_DEVICE is not any class known in C# though. Where does this come from, and how can it be accessed in C#? All I got is the (rather limited) "Screen" class.

Comment: It's not a class, it's the struct in my post.